# Symfony jQuery Datatable dynamic Order

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, datatables

I'm looking for solution for dynamic order by on joined two table query, I have this query where I put a dynamic order by column posted by jQuery datatable.
This is a generic function for order By

```php
public function getAll($columNameOrder) {
    $qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select(array('a','u'))
            ->from('UserCreditHistory', 'uc')
            ->join('User', 'u')
            ->where("a.user = $users ")
            ->orderBy('a.created_at', 'DESC');

        if ($columNameOrder) {
            $qb->orderBy("m.$columNameOrder", $dirOrder);
        }
    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $results = $query->getResult();
    return $results;
}
```

Here the problem is that I can't detect which table column is 'a','u'

```
$qb->orderBy("m.$columNameOrder", $dirOrder);
```

did you have any ideas how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rename column in jquery datable javascript

something like

```
"columns": [
                {"data": "a.name"},
                {"data": "uc.date"},
                {"data": "a.created_at"},
                {"data": "action", "orderable": false},
            ],
```

and in PHP

```
   if ($columNameOrder) {
    $qb->orderBy("$columNameOrder", $dirOrder);
}
```